# Can I use a template and macros in Microsoft word 2019 which is created in Microsoft word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can I use a Macros and Templates in Microsoft Office 2019 which is created in Microsoft Office 2013. If it is not possible, How can I modify and use in Microsoft Office 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the macros don't use features that have been discontinued in the later version. But that's seldom the case. In general, Microsoft is careful to maintain backwards compatibility.